# Why did Vision copy Thor?

Tags: character, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-age-of-ultron

In *[Avengers: Age of Ultron (2015)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2395427/)*, shortly after Vision manifests, he looks at Thor, notices Thor's cape, and generates one of his own.

Why did Vision care to copy this aspect of Thor's appearance?

Comment: All the cool cats wear capes.  Thor, Superman, Batman, Lando....

Comment: I have no evidence to support this, but I suspect it was a quick and easy way to justify why the Vision wears a cape. Capes are not prevalent in the Marvel Cinematic Universe, but the Vision has always had one in the comics, and would look incomplete without it. As Thor is the only member of the team to wear a cape, using him as the inspiration for the look might have felt natural.

Comment: Clearly he didn't watch The Incredibles.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### I think Vision did this because he was trying to blend in.

In the scene where Captain America and Maximoffs trying to stop Stark and Banner from creating an another Ultron, Thor appears and shot a thunder blast into the container that Vision was held in. By doing that, ultimately Thor helped waking up Vision, and after waking up, the first person he sees is Thor. Combining the two facts, Thor was the most recognizable person for Vision in that moment. Then he jumped onto *Thor* and was thrown away. In front of that glass window, he stopped for a moment, gathered his thoughts and made himself wear some kind of greenish suit. Then coming back, he sees Thor is wearing a cape. So Vision did what every kid would do. He copied Thor because he was the most recognizable and closest as a person in world for him.

As others have suggested, it could be also the reason that Vision in comics usually wears a cape.

Comment: Why have you italicized random words?

Comment: @AzorAhai if you see closer, you can see that those words are mostly names :)

Comment: Why did you italicized names?

Comment: Why do you ask? Basically It's like my own formatting. to differ names from the rest of text, to improve recognizability (<- this is not even a word ;) ) on names

Comment: Because it's unusual, distracting, and hard to read, but you do you.

Comment: "it could be also the reason that Vision in comics usually wears a cape." This means "The movie version could be the reason that Vision in the comics wears a cape", which is the opposite of what you mean, presumably.

Answer (score 2):

When Vision comes to life he attacked Thor first, so maybe this was his way of showing gratitude towards him as Thor was responsible in his creation. Also remember cape is a iconic part of Vison in comics, so maybe they have to do it in a reasonable way possible.

It was fully opposite in deleted scene where he did it to compete with him:

Answer (score 2):

## The answer is clear and simple and can be known by simply understanding Vision

Vision had a **mind stone** on him. It was one of the six infinity stones and had **great power**. The power was that **Vision could read the minds**. Just when he was born, he was not fully conscious and seeing a gigantic person (Thor) beside him in an attacking mode, he attacked. But then, when he stopped after being thrown by Thor, he waited and looked at himself and **realised**. Not only about himself but about everyone else also as he could read the minds.

So, when he returned he said -"This was odd" because having a mind stone and attacking even though you know that everybody has good intentions is **odd**.

Then having **read the minds**, he realised that Thor had a role in bringing him to life, and he said him thank you. He also realised that he is closest to Thor (as both are not human) and only Thor has the flying capacity (natural, not like Iron Man) so seeing all these similarities and in honour, he manifested the cape. I hope this answer satisfies you.

References: [Mind Stone](https://time.com/5227586/mcu-six-infinity-stones/)
            [Thor and Vision](https://www.thegamer.com/avengers-marvel-powerful-thor/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Just throwing this out there though but that response is somewhat far from "clear and simple", lol.

Comment: "He also realised that he is closest to Thor (as both are not human) and only Thor has the flying capacity (natural, not like Iron Man)" I think that's a main factor. Capes can make flying look less silly.